# Adding subview to mainWindow causes retain of Controller when removed from superview

Tags: ios

Using this code: The UIViewController (iPadHubVideoPlayer) allocs and then deallocs as it goes out of scope as I would expect.

```
-(void)playiPadHubPlayer{
    iPadHubVideoPlayer *padHubVideoPlayer = [[iPadHubVideoPlayer alloc] init]; 
}
```

However if I add the lines to make the function:

```
-(void)playiPadHubPlayer{
    iPadHubVideoPlayer *padHubVideoPlayer = [[iPadHubVideoPlayer alloc] init];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [appDelegate window];
    [mainWindow addSubview: padHubVideoPlayer.view];
    [padHubVideoPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Then the dealloc method of the UIViewController is never called despite going out of scope and having no obvious pointers to it. So in theory I can never use this way of displaying content without a retain cycle of some kind. Any thoughts as to why this is happening.. is the UIWindow retaining it somehow?

Comment: Could you please post complete code? This snippet is not helpful

Comment: edited code to try and explain it better. I realise it's not a useful bit of code it's just to demonstrate a point. Ideally I would be calling 'removeFromSuperview' somewhere else when finished with it and would have the dealloc method called.

Comment: One way to explain that would be if some strong reference to `iPadHubVideoPlayer` is being made in its `-viewDidLoad` method: view is being loaded in the second case, not in the first one.

Comment: Thanks Jakub I just commented out code in viewDidLoad and this cause dealloc to be called. You were right. Now to find out where the retain is :)

Comment: Choose Profile from the Product menu, and choose the Allocations instrument. Then when you run your code, it should allow you to view where it retained and released your object.